# In which phase of the compiler, the error of an identifier name being too long is detected?

Tags: c, compiler-errors, compilation

If I have a very long name of an identifier ,so in which phase of compiler this error can be detected .
Also if I have some long range of a constant assigned to a variable , is there any error in this ?

```
int a=1987655321467890008766555890765433111223;
```

Comment: these both can be detected when parsing.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: The problem that a number is too large for the object it is initializing (but not too large for the compiler to handle at all) cannot be detected merely by parsing. It requires grammatical analysis to know what object it is initialization and semantic analysis to know it is too large for the object.

Comment: The question title does not match the body.  It ought to be the lexer that keels over on these mishaps.  But error reporting and especially recovery are gritty implementation details, not unlikely that it is delayed until later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C standard defines eight phases of translation:

1. Physical source multibyte characters and trigraph sequences are mapped to characters of the source character set.
2. Each backslash followed by a new-line is deleted (splicing together two lines).
3. The source characters are grouped into preprocessing tokens, and each sequence of white-space characters is replaced by one space, except new-lines are kept.
4. Preprocessing directives and _Pragma operators are executed, and macro invocations are expanded.
5. Source characters in strings and character constants are converted to the execution character set.
6. Adjacent string literals are concatenated.
7. Each preprocessing token is converted into a grammar token, and white-space characters separated tokens are discarded. The resulting tokens are analyzed and translated (compiled).
8. All external references are resolved (the program is linked).

The C standard does not specify in which phase problems in names or values are detected, and the phases are largely conceptual. The phases explain how the C language is understood, not how a compiler must execute.

However, given that, phase 3 is a logical time to detect names that are too long, particularly since names can be preprocessing identifiers, not just identifiers for variables in the program. But this could also be done in phase 4 for preprocessing identifiers or 7 for other identifiers. Also, the compiler might accept long identifiers up to phase 7, but the linker in phase 8 might have a shorter limit, so errors could occur in 8.

Numbers that are much too large for the compiler to handle at all might be detected in phase 3, but 7 is more likely. For numbers that are too large for the object they are being used to initialize, phase 7 is the logical time to detect the problem.